# how can i solve this error: no rule to make target 'Button icon.qml' needed by 'all-am'.stop

Tags: 10.10, compiling, navigation

this is the error when i am trying to make navit in ubuntu10.10

```
   error: no rule to make target 'Button icon.qml' needed by 'all-am'.stop.
```

i dont know how to solve it.somebody help me

Comment: Please add more information to your question, what are you trying to build, how are you doing it ?

Comment: i am trying to rebuild navit.first i configured it,it worked. step1:./configure --enableQML(it worked)  step2:make, then there is error

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo apt-get build-dep navit`, then run `./configure && make` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build the source from [this files](http://download.navit-project.org/navit/src/svn/) you must get the missing .qml files from the SVN repository (https://navit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/navit/trunk/navit) and place them under **navit/gui/qml/skins/navit/**